# Looping through XMLReader to replace special characters in data field

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, excel, xml-parsing

I have XML files I want to put into data sets to export to a database using VB.Net. There is a possibility that new XML files added to this list daily will have special characters (idk why anyone would include "&" in an address entry anyway). After creating the XMLReader, what is the easiest way to replace the escape characters? What would the pseudo code look like? Stream Reader maybe? Or does that work with XMLReader?

Here is my code right now that attempts the data set creation:

```
        For Each file1 In Directory.GetFiles(My.Settings.Local_Meter_Path, "*BadMeter*.xml")

        Dim filecreatedate As String = IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file1)
        FN = Path.GetFileName(file1).ToString()
        xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(Path.Combine(My.Settings.Local_Meter_Path, FN), New XmlReaderSettings())

        ds.ReadXml(xmlFile)
```

and the spot where I'm getting ampersand entity-name parsing error

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="Default"><Data ss:Type="String">1440 COUNTY ROAD 40 X-MAS LIGHT & RV #2 CAMP HILL</Data></Cell>
```